# Can you join GIFs and/or Animated GIFs into a single Animated GIF?

Tags: graphics, 3d, animated-gif

Does anyone know if it's possible to join several gifs or animated gifs into one animated gif (ie. concat the frames together into one master animated gif)?

I'd like to have some server side function to do this.

The file will be identical in dimensions, mode etc, just their content will differ.

Thanks!

Comment: VTC as belongs on superuser.com.  As written, this is not really a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to create the animated gifs (some examples [here](http://www.tjhsst.edu/~dhyatt/supercomp/n401a.html)).